# Spring Boot "unable to resolve class" with Groovy

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy, spring-boot

I'm new to Groovy, Spring Boot, and Gradle (using gradle as well) and am trying to build a small test program.

I have a main class EvalMain and a InputObj class in a com.eval package.

```
@Controller
class EvalMain {
   @RequestMapping("/")
   @ResponseBody
    public static String textTest() {
        def iO = new InputObj("dsa", "dasdsa", "U1dBRw==");
        return iO.xorString();
    }
}
```

when running "spring run EvalMain.groovy" I get the following error:

```
startup failed:
file:<filepath>EvalMain.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class InputObj
 @ line 14, column 18.
       def iO = new InputObj("dsa", "dasdsa", "U1dBRw==");
```

I tried throwing an import at the top but then spring boot complained about this too? What am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

after adding the import:

```
import com.eval.InputObj;
```

I get this error:

```
file:/<filePath>/EvalMain.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class com.eval.InputObj
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import com.eval.InputObj
   ^

1 error
```

Comment: You have to mention where are you expecting `InputObj` from. Add the imports. Also check whether the class is on the classpath. A simple failing example (gist) will be useful.

Comment: Post has been editted to show the error from the import. It's worth noting that my IDE auto-completes the class path in the package while typing the import, but tells me it is an unused import.

And that if I was to run local code like a println instead of trying to use spring run, the class is found and the object functions as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good way to do it, but I was able to run it with "spring run .groovy .groovy" I wonder if there's the equivalent of a makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `spring run *.groovy`.

Spring Boot CLI is for quick prototyping a single Groovy script. It tries to autoload all Spring Boot dependencies, but its your responsibility to include your additional dependencies

- If you have just multiple source files you have to [pass it to the CLI](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli-using-the-cli.html#cli-multiple-source-files).
- If it is an external dependency, include it with a `@Grab`, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli-using-the-cli.html#cli-deduced-grab-annotations).

However, you have Gradle and more than one source file. Therefor it might be the time to switch from the Spring Boot CLI to a normal Gradle project.

Just go to the [guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) and choose "Build with Gradle". Then you will see an example Gradle build file. Also the Gradle Spring Boot [plugin documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html) provides samples.

You can start your application with `gradlew bootRun`.